# Avoiding repetitive prop spreading in Next.js with useContext in child components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, react-context

**LATEST: The issue comes up when calling `useContext` in `<Head>` -- see end of post for more**

I'm trying to build a page that leverages `useContext` in child elements instead of passing spread props repetitively.

I've been trying to *avoid* actually creating this provider in `_app.tsx` (this is a Next.js app, FWIW), as I didn't think it necessary to `createState` and pass function props to set it inside of a child componenlt.

**❌ The approach below results in null context when I try to access it in a child element:**

(I was extra verbose with explicit typings just to see if anything came up statically)

```tsx
// [slug]/[code].tsx
const PageContents: NextPage<InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>> = ({
  company,
  references,
}) => {
  if (!company) {
    return <>Loading...</>
  }
  const { name } = company

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <Metadata />
      </Head>

      <p>Hi { name }!</p>
    </>
  )
}

const Resume: NextPage<InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>> = (
  props
) => {
  //  This is where I was trying to create a parent "layer" so useContext would work.
  return (
    <CompanyContext.Provider value={props ? props.company : null}>
      <PageContents {...props} />
    </CompanyContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default Resume

// getStaticProps omitted
```

```tsx
// context/CompanyContext.tsx
import type { Company } from '@prisma/client'
import type { ReactNode } from 'react'
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react'

export type LightweightCompany = Omit<Company, 'png' | 'resumeMessage'>
const CompanyContext = createContext<LightweightCompany | null>(null)

export const useCompany = () => {
  const currentCompanyContext = useContext(CompanyContext)

  if (!currentCompanyContext) {
    throw new Error(
      'useCompany has to be used within <CompanyContext.Provider>'
    )
  }

  return currentCompanyContext
}


//  I'm not even sure if this is needed;
//    I've seen this pattern used broadly, 
//    but don't see how it's doing much for my use case
export function CompanyProvider({
  value,
  children,
}: {
  value: LightweightCompany
  children: ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <CompanyContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</CompanyContext.Provider>
  )
}
export default CompanyContext
```

```tsx
// components/Metadata.tsx

// this will be one (of many) in-page components
// that I'd like to avoid {...props} spreading
// into, if possible.

export default function Metadata() {
  const { color, name } = useCompany()
  // useCompany throws an error here ❌
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a design pattern I'm missing (or misusing) that would allow me to keep the code relatively clean/low boilerplate and have the context passed in.

TIA!

I've tried HOC / currying:

```tsx
// context/Company.tsx
const withCompany = (Component: React.FC<PageProps>) => (props: PageProps) =>
  (
    <CompanyContext.Provider value={props.company}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </CompanyContext.Provider>
  )
```

```tsx
// page.tsx

export default withCompany(Page)
```

UPDATE: This is strange, but when I do a bare-bones example, https://replit.com/@timfee/LimeDeliriousLinux#pages/index.tsx - it works as expected.

UPDATE 2: Aaah! When I took the code out of `<Head>` it worked fine. Seems like a nextjs issue?

Comment: Clarification on where I am right now, it seems useContext() inside of a child element of <Head> breaks

Comment: I don't know about the inner workings of `useContext` any better than you do. Drawing from my own experience, I'd wrap `CompanyContext.Provider` around the html that `<PageContents>` return

Comment: Yep... if you peek at [https://replit.com/@timfee/LimeDeliriousLinux#pages/index.tsx](a minimal repro), it looks like my code was more or less correct and that it's an issue with it living inside `<Head />`.

I confused the hell out of ChatGPT asking it to debug; it was as confused as me :) 

[Flagged it](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45644) to the nextjs folks to see if this is WAI

Comment: Hope Vercel will have an answer to this.